# g++.exe fatal error no input files compilation terminated codelite КАК ИСПРАВИТЬ

Tags: c++, codelite

Захотел научиться программировать на C++. Скачал CodeLite, создал workspace, new project и скопировал текст программы "Hellow world!" в новый файл.
Выдало такую ошибку. Что делать?

Comment: И как выглядит ваш проект?

Comment: В нем есть единственная папка src, состоящая из единственного файла с кодом для вывода на экран "Hellow World!".

Comment: CodeLite - лишь IDE, надстройка. Попробуйте собрать проект в консоли. Если собирается - разбирайтесь с настройками CodeLite, если нет - видимо проблемы с MinGW.

Comment: такую ошибку gcc выдает, когда ему на компиляцию не передали ни одного файла. Это может быть как и то, что файл не добавлен в проект, так и то, что ошибка самой IDE. Но  у меня есть подозрение, что вся загввоздка в том, что в путях к cpp файлу есть пробелы/кириллица

Comment: Дело не в имени -- gcc "понимает" любые имена, валидные в файловой системе